# Nested Transaction handling in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

I have series of models to save on success of first model and is starting to look as below with many IF conditions :

Version : Yii 1
Using NestedPDO

Is their better way to do transactions in Yii ?

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
try {
    if (!$firstmodel->save()) {
        throw new Exception('FirstModel cannot be saved.');
    } else {
        if (!$secondmodel->save()) {
            throw new Exception('SecondModel cannot be saved.');
        } else {               
            if (!$thirdModel->save()) {
                 throw new Exception('ThirdModel cannot be saved.');
            }
        }
    }

    $transaction->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollback();
}
```

Comment: Add a rollback before manually throwing exceptions.

Comment: @crafter, wont the rollback in catch Exception handle that ?

Comment: You are correct it will. The rollback in the try would be unnecessary. I will delete my comment.

Comment: If you are worried about the nestedness, you can leave the 'else' statement. The next save() will only be reached if an error in save is not caught, or no unexpected errors happen,

Comment: @crafter, is it possible to extend ActiveRecord save() such that it does this centrally and I dont have to write everywhere throw statements in each method + transaction boilerplate is also reduced ( like in java / spring Transactional annotation ) ?

Comment: If you want to do this I will suggest creating a class that extends ActiveRecord, then add the necessary mechanisms there. Your model class will then extend that new class.

Comment: Look here (for Yii 1  but should work for Yii 2) - http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/18178-transaction-problem-by-overriding-save-method/